# Restrict node.js project to run on a specific server

Tags: javascript, node.js, licensing, source-code-protection

Since our employer has a physical access to the server that runs our node.js project, we are worried about the js files that can be owned and copied to another server (even after obfuscation).

Then is there a way to prevent the JavaScript code from being executed on another system?

My idea is to check some systems information to know if it's the right server.

Comment: That's probably pretty hard to do without a hardware key.  Even then, someone could probably emulate the environment. I don't have an answer, but curious to see what answer you get.

Comment: BTW, who cares about this and why exactly?  Like, is it the employer who doesn't want it copied or you as the developer that don't want it copied?  More context might inform someone who could give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks dear Matt. We are the developer team and we don't want others to copy our project. Specially the employer who has a physical access to server.

Comment: if that's the case, then perhaps you should assume the project will get copied, and charge the customer enough to make it worth your while.  In other words, think of the software as "his" once you sell it to him, rather than "yours."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [node-machine-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-machine-id) and [javascript-obfuscator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator).

The former allows you to generate a device fingerprint that you can embed into the software for verifying.

The latter allows you to obfuscate the code so it is not editable or readable by users with access to the file system.

**And yes, node-machine-id does not work if the environment is virtualized, like a VM or container**